# Mysql Trigger update multiple rows using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have a table that contains data like this
 [image]

i want a trigger to update the corresping ptranx to 0 when the main id is  0.

For example when the id 460 is 0, then the ids 462 and 463 becomes 0 too.

Comment: Bad news- you cannot update the table in the trigger called by the table.

Comment: you'll need to wrap the update functionality in a stored proc I think and have your application call that instead of doing a direct update. The stored procedure can then handle this kind of extra logic.